# Como totalizar o numero de registros por Categoria utilizando um VIEW SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite.
Não estou encontrando uma maneira de, usando ou somente chamando uma VIEW, contar quanto professores existem numa determinada categoria, cuja saída deve ser a categoria e a quantidade.

A VIEW que fiz é a seguinte:

```
CREATE VIEW VMostraProfessor AS
SELECT pro_nome AS Nome, cat_nome AS Categoria, tit_nome AS Titulação, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), pro_nascimento, 103) AS Nascimento, cid_nome AS Cidade, pro_sexo AS Sexo FROM Professor p
    inner join categoria c ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
    inner join titulacao t ON t.tit_id = p.tit_id
    inner join cidade cd ON cd.cid_ID = p.cid_id;
```

Tem como fazer isso na chamada ou dentro da view? (Preferencialmente na chamada)

[image: Saída gerada pela VIEW]

Grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cmp.categoria,
       COUNT(1) AS quantidade
  FROM VMostraProfessor cmp
 GROUP BY cmp.categoria
```

Comment: Nossa!! Obrigadão! Funcionou perfeitamente.
Tão simples e eu nem liguei...